# Accessing pagination info from liferay search-container in SpringMVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay

I am developing a Portlet with Liferay (using liferay-ui in the JSP) and SpringMVC.

I have the following code in my JSP:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="5" emptyResultsMessage="no books!">
  <%
    List<Book> bookList = (List<Book>)request.getAttribute("bookList");
    List<Book> bookListView = ListUtil.subList(bookList, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd());
  %>
<liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%= bookListView %>" total="${numberOfBooks}">

</liferay-ui:search-container-results>
  ...
```

I'd really like to get rid of the Java Code Block in the JSP and have the bookListView as model attribute just like numberOfBooks in the above code.

However, I can't find a way to access searchContainer from the Spring Controller to get the start and end of the pagination...

Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: see if this code in your controller can help: `SearchContainer searchContainer = request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:search:searchContainer");`

Comment: I tried:

@ModelAttribute("bookList")
public List<Book> getBookList(RenderRequest request) throws SystemException {
SearchContainer searchContainer = (SearchContainer)request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:search:searchContainer");


But searchContainer is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SearchContainer<Book> searchContainer = new SearchContainer<Book>(renderRequest, renderResponse.createRenderURL(), null, "there are no books");
```

Or else,

You can get the parameters from request: `delta=20` & `cur=2`

where `cur` is the current page which is requested and `delta` is the total number of items on a page.

With this you can calculate the start (0,20,40, ...) and end (19,39,59, ...) as does liferay's [`SearchContainer`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/SearchContainer.java#L452) with this method:

```
private void _calculateStartAndEnd() {
    _start = (_cur - 1) * _delta;
    _end = _start + _delta;

    _resultEnd = _end;

    if (_resultEnd > _total) {
        _resultEnd = _total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a suitable SearchContainer in your controller and add it to your model. As Prakash K already said this SearchContainer could look like this:

```
SearchContainer<Book> searchContainer = new SearchContainer<Book>(renderRequest, renderResponse.createRenderURL(), null, "there are no books");
```

Because of the two parameter renderRequest and renderResponse you can not use the @ModelAttribute annotation to add the SearchContainer as a model attribute.

Then the JSP can be written like this:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container searchContainer="${model.searchContainer}" delta="${model.searchContainer.delta}" deltaParam="books_delta">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${model.searchContainer.results}" total="${model.searchContainer.total}"/>    

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="Book"
        keyProperty="primaryKey"
        modelVar="book">
        ...
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="${model.searchContainer}"/>

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

The attribute deltaParam can be used to configure the used URL parameter