# Setting SearchContainer in portlet to use it in JSP using EL and JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, liferay, portlet

I am trying to use `SearchContainer` in my liferay application. Currently I've to use JSP Scriplets to set the *results* in `<liferay-ui:search-container-results>` tags. This is the snippet so far:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="there-are-no-courses" delta="5">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
        <%
            List<Course> tempResults = ActionUtil.getCourses(renderRequest);

            results = ListUtil.subList(tempResults, 
                                   searchContainer.getStart(), 
                                   searchContainer.getEnd());

            total = tempResults.size();
            pageContext.setAttribute("results", results);
            pageContext.setAttribute("total", total);
        %>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row ...></liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Now, I would like to change those scriplets to EL. I [found one post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12069927/1679863) regarding the same issue, but that is using `Spring MVC`. And I've no idea where to write the below line as given in the answer to that question, in portlets:

```
SearchContainer<Book> searchContainer = new SearchContainer<Book>(renderRequest, renderResponse.createRenderURL(), null, "there are no books");
```

In can't write it in my portlet action, as the parameter in my action is `ActionRequest` and `ActionResponse`, which does not define the method `createRenderURL()`. How would I get the `PortletURL`?

Where should I write the above statement? Currently I'm writing in the same action from where I'm returning to this page. Am I doing it right? Here's the action that I'm firing from the same page, as the `search-container` is in:

```
public void addCourse(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) 
        throws Exception {

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = 
            (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

    Course course = ActionUtil.courseFromRequest(request);

    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (CourseRegValidator.validateCourse(course, errors)) {
        CourseLocalServiceUtil.addCourse(course, themeDisplay.getUserId());
        SessionMessages.add(request, "course-added-successfully");

        // I thought I might put it here.
        // But I don't know what to pass as `PortletURL` in constructor of SearchContainer
    } else {
        SessionErrors.add(request, "fields-required");
    }
}
```

I want that, everytime a `Course` is added, it is rendered in my search container, on the same page from where I'm firing the `addCourse` action.

And yes, my portlet extends `MVCPortlet`.

---

**UPDATE**:

Ok, I figured out a few part.

- For the first time when portlet is loaded, I can override the `doView` method in my portlet, and then add the `SearchContainer` in `renderRequest` there, as I've access to it in `doView`.
- But again, when I go on to `editCourse()` action, where I'am doing a `response.setRenderParameter()`, to send it to another jsp page. And in that JSP page, I'm firing an `updateCourse()` action.
- Now, from `updateCourse()` action, I'm again using `response.setRenderParameter()` to send it to the original JSP page, where I'm using *Search Container*. But now, since it is not going through `doView()` method, I can't create the `SearchContainer` and add it to request.

So, is there any work-around here? How to make sure that the attribute I set in `renderRequest` in `doView` method is available in `updateCourse` method? I know that doesn't sound practical, as it is completely a new request, but is there any other way?

One work-around I can think of is to set the attribute in larger scope, like `session` or `context` instead of `renderRequest`. But, I won't need that attribute anywhere else. So, I don't think that would be appropriate.

Any inputs?

---

**Update 2**:

Just now, I used:

```
actionResponse.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
```

in place of:

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", jspPage);
```

And it worked, as it now goes through `doView()` method. Just wanted to ask, is this the appropriate way? What's the difference between two methods when we are setting render parameter to the same JSP page, where `doView` methods redirects?

---

My Current `doView` method looks like:

```
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) 
        throws IOException, PortletException {

    SearchContainer<Course> searchContainer = 
            new SearchContainer<Course>(renderRequest, renderResponse.createRenderURL(), null, "there-are-no-courses");

    searchContainer.setDelta(5);
    List<Course> tempResults = ActionUtil.getCourses(renderRequest);

    List<Course> results = ListUtil.subList(tempResults, 
                                    searchContainer.getStart(), 
                                    searchContainer.getEnd());

    searchContainer.setTotal(tempResults.size());
    searchContainer.setResults(results);

    renderRequest.setAttribute("searchContainer", searchContainer);
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

Comment: Can't you set the `results` & `total` in a request attribute and send it to the jsp? Also the `doView` method is called everytime the action method is completed as part of the portlet life-cycle.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to set `searchContainer` attribute to use it as value for `searchContainer` attribute in `<liferay-ui:search-container`? Or I guess that attribute is not needed at all. But I saw it being used at some places.

Comment: So, I don't need to add either of the last two invocation. The `setPortletMode` one is implicit, and that is what I should do right?

Comment: @PrakashK And even though I set `results` and `total` in request attribute in `doView` I would face the same problem. Those will be lost on the new request.

Comment: Let us go step-by-step: __1)__ Whenever you render a portlet it is rendered through the `doView` method and not directly through the action methods. __2)__ the `results` and `total` set as `renderRequest.setAttribute("searchResults", courses)` and `renderRequest.setAttribute("searchTotal", total)` in `doView` will be available in the `view.jsp` as `${searchResults}` and `${searchTotal}`. __3)__ Everytime you perform any action the `doView` will be called after that and the `searchResults` and `searchTotal` will be set again and will be shown.

Comment: contd. __4)__ or you can just set the `searchContainer` in the `doView` method itself or else __5)__ calculate the `start` and `end` based on the parameters `delta` and `cur` you will get from the `request`. Let me know if I am not understanding anything.

Comment: @PrakashK I have added my current `doView` method how it looks like. Can you take a look whether it's ok? You said, I can't set `searchContainer` in `doView` method, but that is what I'm doing it currently. And what's the use of `cur`, I don't set it anywhere?

Comment: Yes this is what I said in my `4th` point

Comment: @PrakashK. Ah! Thanks a lot. You can probably combine those comments to make an answer, so that I can accept it. Also, what's the use of `cur`? I didn't use it anywhere?

Comment: `cur` as explained in my other answer which you have linked is the current page number which is requested, it is used by the search-container. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923082/setting-searchcontainer-in-portlet-to-use-it-in-jsp-using-el-and-jstl?noredirect=1#comment26221981_17923082) to answer:

1. Whenever you render a portlet it is rendered through the doView method and not directly through the action methods as part of the portlet life-cycle.
2. the results and total set as renderRequest.setAttribute("searchResults", courses) and renderRequest.setAttribute("searchTotal", total) in doView will be available in the view.jsp as ${searchResults} and ${searchTotal}.
3. Everytime you perform any action the doView will be called after that and the searchResults and searchTotal will be set again and will be shown.
4. or you can just set the `searchContainer` in the doView method itself as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12074370/468763) which you had linked in your question.