# Passing values in `<portlet:param>` using EL

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, el, portlet

I'm trying to pass a parameter with `<portlet:actionURL>` to a portlet in liferay, but it turns out that, using EL to pass values in not working, however, using JSP expression tag is working fine.

Here's my relevant code:

```
<%
    ResultRow row = (ResultRow)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.SEARCH_CONTAINER_RESULT_ROW);

    Course course = (Course) row.getObject();
    long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
    String name = Course.class.getName();
    String primaryKey = String.valueOf(course.getPrimaryKey());

%>

<liferay-ui:icon-menu>

    <c:if test="<%= permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, name, primaryKey, ActionKeys.UPDATE)%>">
        <portlet:actionURL name="editCourse" var="editURL">
            <portlet:param name="resourcePrimaryKey" value="${primaryKey}"/>
        </portlet:actionURL>

        <liferay-ui:icon image="edit" message="Edit" url="${editURL}" />
    </c:if>
</liferay-ui:icon-menu>
```

As you see, in `<portlet:param>` tag, I have used EL for passing *value* attribute. But it doesn't work, and I receive the value as `0` for `"resourcePrimaryKey"` in my action method, when I do:

```
long courseId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "resourcePrimaryKey");
// courseId is 0 here
```

However, if I use JSP expression tag in place of EL, it works fine:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="editCourse" var="editURL">
    <portlet:param name="resourcePrimaryKey" value="<%= primaryKey %>"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Now, I get the required value for `"resourcePrimaryKey"`.

Can anyone figure what's going on here? Surprisingly, EL at other place work fine, as you see - `${editURL}` value for *url* attribute, is working fine, and redirecting to the corresponding url.

I came across [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/portals-jetspeed-user/200705.mbox/%3C7e675420705150116u1fe50ecay89f57bec756a4f63@mail.gmail.com%3E) on apache mail archive regarding the same issue, but that doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable in the scriptlet **cannot** be used directly in an EL, you would first need to set it like:

```
<c:set var="primKey"><%=primaryKey %></c:set>
```

and use `${primKey}` or set it as a request attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("primKey", primaryKey);
```

Clearly, better would be to directly use the expression.

Also regarding the `${editURL}` working, it is a portlet jsp tag which sets the variable in the page context so that it is available to the EL.

Our [el](/questions/tagged/el) wiki is a good place to know these things, look out for the heading `Make objects available to EL` for this question :-)

Comment: Aha! Didn't knew about that. Thanks :) Actually, I earlier also tried using `<c:set>`, but there also I was using `${primaryKey}` to set the attribute, so that was supposed to show same behaviour as you said. Got it now. And also, please can you take a look at [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17923082/1679863)?

Comment: And is there a way to convert those scriplets to JSTL in the first place? or set those values - `ResultRow`, etc at some other place?

Comment: I'm coming to this place using this tag in previous JSP page - `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
   path="/html/courseadmin/admin_actions.jsp" align="right" />`. Can I send it some where else?

Comment: I think these questions are related to another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923082/setting-searchcontainer-in-portlet-to-use-it-in-jsp-using-el-and-jstl). It would be better to discuss that question in that place instead of mixing it with this question.

Comment: Anyways, I am afraid liferay is not a big fan of scriptless JSPs and there philosophy also encourages use of `scriptlets` so the answer is No you can't convert those scriptlets to JSTL.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my other question that you linked? specially last 2 updates?

Comment: Here is the [philosophy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.manning.com%2Fsezov%2FLiA_SampleChapter-04.pdf&ei=PLj3UYSqMra-4APPvYCYDw&usg=AFQjCNHMwdv4Wfyk22PgE6WjO6Ksl0mcyQ&sig2=3RoyCg6GWXD-nCM13817DQ) of liferay regarding scriptlets and JSPs from the official book `Liferay in Action`. Jump to heading `4.2.2 Having one location for JSP dependencies`.

Comment: I'm reading from that book only. I've read that point. I see that somewhere it's not possible to avoid scriplets. At least till now, I've seen that. Thanks for that. I'll take a closer look at that topic though. :)